# Internet Explorer CSS gradient handling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gradient

I've got a style created which will give all "buttons" gradient backgrounds. The gotcha is not all buttons are actually buttons, some are links which are styled to look like a button.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="gradient" /><br />
<input type="button" value="button" class="gradient" /><br />
<a href="" class="gradient">Link</a>
```

To these I've applied the following styles:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #20799d, #5cb9df); /* FF3.6 */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #20799d),color-stop(1, #5cb9df)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#20799d, #5cb9df); /* Chrome 10+, Saf6 */
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #20799d, #5cb9df); 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#20799d', EndColorStr='#5cb9df'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```

The issue is found here. IE 7-9 will apply the gradient to the `<input>` elements but NOT the `<a>` element. All other browsers work. Is there a fix to get IE to give `<a>` tags gradients?

You can test and see the results here, only IE causes the last to have no gradient. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wSuJj/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `display:inline-block` fixed the gradient for me in IE 6, 7, and 8.

http://jsfiddle.net/wSuJj/3/

I'm not sure why, it might have to do with hasLayout, hopefully someone can come along and explain.

There's still some inconsistency with the borders in IE6 and 7 as well that doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: @JeremyB.: Not directly related: Check out the border behavior in IE6 and IE7, it's a bit off and I can't figure out why at the moment.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 don't support the rounded corners, but we've got that covered under "progressive enhancement". Having certain buttons coming out white was a problem though.

Comment: What I mean is that the button does not look like the link.

Comment: Buttons in IE are hard to style well.

Answer (score 2):

To apply filters to element, it has to [`hasLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Personally, I use `zoom:1`.

Comment: I'd prefer `zoom:1` as well, but for some reason it didn't work in the fiddle?

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work. Which IE verison have you tried? IE 8+ needs `-ms-filter:`.

Comment: I tried 6-8, and just tried with `-ms-filter` instead of `filter` and it seemed to make it worse. Could you demo a working version with `zoom:1`?

Comment: @atlavis: You're right - 6 and 7 are indeed showing the gradient, but not 8 for some reason.

Comment: I think IE 8 needs `-ms-filter:` + apostrophes, like `-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="#20799d", EndColorStr="#5cb9df")';` I'm not able to check it now but I hope it works http://jsfiddle.net/wSuJj/6/

Comment: @atlavis: Doesn't work in IE8, at least not for me on a true IE8 Win 7 installation.

Comment: This answer should be marked as final solution. It works finally. Good answer!